# Bitwise operators. Decimal and Hexa

Tags: c

Good evening.

Can someone explain me why the following code runs the message from IF condition?

```
if ((~7 & 0x000f) == 8)
   printf("Honesty is the best policy\n");
```

From what I know ~7 = 11111001 and 0x000f= 00001111

Thank you!

Comment: -7 is not ~7, you are off by 1: 11111000

Comment: `calculator` in Windows (programmer mode), or `gdb` (`p/t ~7` ...see `help x`), or `wcalc` are all good tools to use to check your assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I know ~7 = 11111001 and 0x000f= 00001111

That's incorrect from two points of view.

1. 7 is of type `int`. If you are on a platform where `sizeof(int)` is 4, `7` in binary will be `00000000 00000000 00000000 0000111`. Hence, `~7` will be `1111111 11111111 11111111 1111000`.
2. Even if you ignore the first 3 bytes, the bits of the last byte are also different.

Comment: Basically, ~ is for one's complement, and - is for two's ?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you explain why the output from here is 2?
`int a = 2;`
`if (a >> 1)`
`printf("%d\n", a);`
Isn't shifting the bits one time to the right? 
from 0010 to 0001?

Comment: @MarcoMărculeţ, If you look at the bits of the last byte for `2`, it is `00000010`. If you right shift the bits by one, you get `00000001`, which is `1`. `if ( a >> 1 )` translates to `if ( 1 )`. `a >> 2` does not change the value of `a` to `1`. It just evaluates to `1`. To change `a`, you can use `a >>= 1`.

Comment: That makes sense. Let me get the " >>= " part, because it's new for me. In words you can explain it like: "shift it to the right one time and change the value also"?

Comment: @MarcoMărculeţ, that's correct. it's similar to using `a += 10`.

Comment: @MarcoMărculeţ, you are welcome. I am glad I was able to help.

Comment: @MarcoMărculeţ : SO is not a discussion forum, if you have more questions, post new questions, do not start a semi-private discussion in the comments.  The questions about what specific operators do can be answered using any C reference text.

Answer (score 3):

-7 (indeed 11111001)
is not ~7 (11111000)

You are off by 1.

```
11111000
&
00001111
==
00001000
```

is true.

*(This answer follows the questions obvious lead, in using a simplified 8 bit model for the involved values.)*

Answer (score 1):

here 7=00000111 1's complement of7 is 11111000 hex code of 0X0000f =00001111 bitwise and operation of 11111000 & 00001111=00001000 so ans is 8 i.e non-zero value so if loop get executed it will print "Honesty is the best policy".